# Missing element breaks script (getElementById)

Tags: javascript

If the ID doesn't exist the script breaks. Why?

How to chache the_lis?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
alert('this will alert');
var the_id = document.getElementById('a_id_that_does_not_exist'),
the_lis = the_id.getElementsByTagName('li');
alert('this will NOT alert');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should check to see that `the_id` exists or not first using an `if` statement, other wise an exception will be thrown.

```
window.onload = function(){
alert('this will alert');
var the_id = document.getElementById('a_id_that_does_not_exist');
if (the_id != undefined)
    the_lis = the_id.getElementsByTagName('li');
alert('this will NOT alert');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the first element does not exist `the_id` will be `null`. Calling the method `getElementsByTagName` on `null` will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

`the_id` is null, and `null` does not have a `getElementsByTagName` method. Duh.

Either make sure the ID exists before you write your code, or check for it explicitly with something like:

```
var the_lis = the_id ? the_id.getElementsByTagName('li') : [];
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, getElementsByTagName returns an array. However before that happens, the_id should be null or undefined because it does not exist, therefore you are trying to call getElementsByTagName on a null instance.

I would suggest (unless not applicable) use jquery to do whatever you're trying to do, and use firebug to debug your JavaScript

Comment: [getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-A6C9094) returns a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-536297177), not an array. jQuery won't help, it will silently fail. Would you rather know about the error immeditately at the point it occurs, or at some later time when it may well be obfuscated by other code and processing?

Comment: I stand corrected sir! I am learning much about JavaScript at the moment so my knowledge so far is a little flakey!

Comment: That's fine, becoming involved in discussions is an extremely useful learning tool.